# How do i create a file so that i can download it on my local computer in google colab?

Tags: python, python-3.x, svg, google-colaboratory

I'm manipulating some svg's using lib-svgpathtools and have made use of the wsvg() function. This directly saves the created file(ex:file1.svg)on the left panel under file section of
Google colaboratory. Under content just like that..now that i have multiple files to be created its difficult to go on downloading each on of them ..instead is there any way to get them directly into a folder and further that folder to my system?? its being difficult since this file creation is happening in this function. Plz help me out!
Thanks a lot in advance!!

```
 wsvg(paths = paths, attributes = attributes, svg_attributes=svg_attributes, filename='file' + str(num) + '.svg')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could zip your svgs and download the zip from the side-panel.

```py
from zipfile import ZipFile
import glob

with ZipFile('./all_of_the_svgs.zip', 'w') as zipObj:
    for i in glob.glob('./your_folder/*.svg'):
        zipObj.write(i)
```

If the files go directly into the root folder of the left panel, then it would just be: `for i in glob.glob('./*.svg'):`

---

To save the svgs directly into a folder in the left side panel you can probably just change the filename argument to include the name of the folder you want it put into:

Before:

```py
 wsvg(paths = paths, attributes = attributes, svg_attributes=svg_attributes, filename='file' + str(num) + '.svg')
```

To:

```py
 wsvg(paths = paths, attributes = attributes, svg_attributes=svg_attributes, filename='./folder_name/' + 'file' + str(num) + '.svg')
```

You would need to create the folder with "folder_name" in the left panel first though.

Comment: Thanks a ton!!! this totally worked!!! Have a nice day:)